# Making space between two tables

Tags: tables, threeparttable, xtable

[image]

How can we make space between two tables, arranged in columns, where each table contains four columns?

I have two tables with three columns each, but want four columns.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! please explain your issue better, for example show us a short compilable tex code resulting in your issue ...

Comment: What four columns do you mean?

Comment: Did you study how to make tables in LaTeX?
And you can even use these sites to have the tables code in LaTeX generated for you: https://www.tablesgenerator.com and https://www.latex-tables.com

Answer (score 1):

I have a vague idea what you're trying to achieve but before guessing, here is some code which typesets the table above.  Note that the code shows 3 tables to compare: Vanilla LaTeX, with `threeparttable` and with `floatrow`.  Formatting of the caption is done by the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{erewhon}
\usepackage[utopia]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{caption,floatrow,booktabs,siunitx,threeparttable}

\captionsetup[table]{%
  labelsep  = newline,
  labelfont = {footnotesize,bf},
  textfont  = footnotesize}

\floatsetup{%
  font        = small,
  floatrowsep = qquad,
  captionskip = 5pt
}

\floatsetup[table]{%
  style = Plaintop
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!t]
  \RawFloats
  \centering
  \caption{Vanilla \LaTeX\ -- Eigenvalues $\omega^2_0$ and
    $\omega^2_1$ of Eq. (26) for $r_0=1.1$ and varying, for the two
    strings configurations}
  \label{tab:vanill-latex}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}*{2}{%
    S[table-format=1.1]
    S[table-format={$-$}1.3]
    S[table-format=1.3]%
    }%
    @{}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{$x_1$ configuration}
    & \multicolumn{3}{l@{}}{$x_3$ configuration} \\%
    \cmidrule(r){1-3}\cmidrule(l){4-6}
    \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{B}
    & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$\omega^2_0$}
    & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$\omega^2_1$}
    & \multicolumn{1}{l}{B}
    & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$\omega^2_0$}
    & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$\omega^2_1$} \\
    \midrule
    0   & -1.370 & 7.638 & 0   & -1.370 & 7.638 \\
    0.3 & -1.327 & 7.531 & 0.3 & -1.317 & 7.548 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \RawFloats
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{With \texttt{threeparttable} -- Eigenvalues $\omega^2_0$
      and $\omega^2_1$ of Eq. (26) for $r_0=1.1$ and varying, for the
      two strings configurations}
    \label{tab:threeparttab}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}*{2}{%
      S[table-format=1.1]
      S[table-format={$-$}1.3]
      S[table-format=1.3]%
      }%
      @{}}
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{$x_1$ configuration}
      & \multicolumn{3}{l@{}}{$x_3$ configuration} \\%
      \cmidrule(r){1-3}\cmidrule(l){4-6}
      \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{B}
      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$\omega^2_0$}
      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$\omega^2_1$}
      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{B}
      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$\omega^2_0$}
      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$\omega^2_1$} \\
      \midrule
      0   & -1.370 & 7.638 & 0   & -1.370 & 7.638 \\
      0.3 & -1.327 & 7.531 & 0.3 & -1.317 & 7.548 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \begin{floatrow}
    \ttabbox{%
      \sisetup{table-number-alignment=left}
      \begin{tabular}{@{}*{2}{%
        S[table-format=1.1]
        S[table-format={$-$}1.3]
        S[table-format=1.3]%
        }%
        @{}}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{$x_1$ configuration}
        & \multicolumn{3}{l@{}}{$x_3$ configuration}\\%
        \cmidrule(r){1-3}\cmidrule(l){4-6}
        \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{B}
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$\omega^2_0$}
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$\omega^2_1$}
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{B}
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$\omega^2_0$}
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$\omega^2_1$}\\
        \midrule
        0   & -1.370 & 7.638 & 0   & -1.370 & 7.638 \\
        0.3 & -1.327 & 7.531 & 0.3 & -1.317 & 7.548 \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}%
    }{%
      \caption{With \texttt{floatrow} -- Eigenvalues $\omega^2_0$ and
        $\omega^2_1$ of Eq. (26) for $r_0=1.1$ and varying, for the
        two strings configurations}%
      \label{tab:with-floatrow}%
    }
  \end{floatrow}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

which looks like this:
[image]

Note that there aren't two tables, this is only table where the space between the columns is added by the command `\cmidrule(r){1-3}\cmidrule(l){4-6}`.  I suggest you have a look at the manuals of `caption` ,`floatrow`, `booktabs`, `siunitx`, `threeparttable` to figure out what the macros do.

Finally, provide code in future when you ask a question.  It is a pain to type stuff from a picture.